# Flutter while Making any Http Request on real device to server reports wrong port number in logs

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

```
static String baseurl ="http://10.183.121.43:5000/";

try { Response response = await Dio().get(constant.baseurl+"hello/"); print(response); } catch (e) { print(e); }


----------
try {
                                     await RawSocket.connect("10.183.121.43", 5000);
                                   } catch (e) {
                                     print(e);
                                   }

----------


SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 10.183.121.43, port = 55705
```

How I can fix it?
I am working on a real device ..  and from the real device this IP and port working properly because I tested with the android app postman I am getting  response of my api ..

Same if i used Ngrok and pass ngrok address instead of IP  then it also working ..  But  by  Passing IP [http://10.183.121.43:5000/"](http://10.183.121.43:5000/%22)    this is  not working

Comment: the ip is not exposed to the internet or the device is not on the same network, that is confirmed by you are being able to connect using ngrok, so actively use ngrok, remember server apps you run on your computer are not exposed to the internet, that is why tools like ngrok exists!

Comment: device is  same network becase  i test with android app postman its working perfectly  ..  but  in flutter  when i am using ip   it not working

Comment: this is  local  network  and its  working with postman from android device  by  using application .

Comment: Same  i tested on the android native application using java its working perfeclty

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73325

Comment: use the native socket

Comment: can you post minimum fully working code, client and server

Comment: i am doing simple poc by   IP and port  no in url ..  if  i am  working with domain its  working ..

Comment: https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/1023